# Doctrine Fixtures Bundle wont install on Symfony 2.4.10

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am currently using symfony 2.4.10 i wanted to install Doctrine Fixtures Bundle but when i use composer `require --dev doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle`
to install it i get this :

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.0.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.0.2 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.0.1 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.0.0 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.4.3 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.4.2 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.4.1 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.4.0 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.3.9 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.3.8 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.3.7 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.3.6 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.3.5 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.3.4 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.3.3 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.3.2 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.3.15 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.3.14 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.3.13 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.3.12 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.3.11 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.3.10 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.3.1 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.3.0 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.2.9 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.2.8 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.2.7 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.2.6 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.2.5 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.2.4 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.2.3 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.2.2 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.2.14 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.2.13 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.2.12 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.2.11 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.2.10 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.2.1 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.2.0 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.1.9 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.1.8 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.1.7 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.1.6 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.1.5 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.1.4 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.1.3 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.1.2 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.1.10 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.1.1 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.1.0 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.0.9 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.0.8 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.0.7 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.0.6 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.0.5 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.0.4 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.0.3 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.0.2 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.0.1 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.0.0 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle v2.4.0 requires symfony/doctrine-bridge ~2.7|~3.0|~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/doctrine-bridge[v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35, v2.7.36, v2.7.37, v2.7.38, v2.7.39, v2.7.4, v2.7.40, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9, v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.14, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.13, v3.3.14, v3.3.15, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.2, v3.4.3, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3].
    - doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle v2.4.1 requires symfony/doctrine-bridge ~2.7|~3.0|~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/doctrine-bridge[v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35, v2.7.36, v2.7.37, v2.7.38, v2.7.39, v2.7.4, v2.7.40, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9, v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.14, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.13, v3.3.14, v3.3.15, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.2, v3.4.3, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3].
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.11|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.12|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.13|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.14|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.15|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.16|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.17|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.18|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.19|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.20|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.21|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.22|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.23|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.24|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.25|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.26|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.27|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.28|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.29|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.30|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.31|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.32|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.33|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.34|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.35|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.36|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.37|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.38|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.39|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.40|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.11|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.12|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.13|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.14|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.15|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.16|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.17|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.18|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.19|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.20|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.21|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.22|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.23|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.24|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.25|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.26|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.27|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.28|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.29|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.30|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.31|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.32|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.33|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.8.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.10
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony (locked at v2.4.10, required as 2.4.*) -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.4.10].
    - Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle ^2.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle[v2.4.0, v2.4.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

well i know that maybe i should use an other version of php but now i am at a point that i can't come back please help me i dont know if there's an other version of Doctrine Fixtures Bundle that workd with symfony 2.4.10 
note : i am using php 5.4

Comment: Can you try running `composer require symfony/doctrine-bridge:~2.7` first and then try this again, please? I'm not sure why Composer isn't able to figure this out by itself, but it doesn't seem to be working far enough back in the versions of `doctrine-bridge` that it's attempting to install.

Comment: thank you i installed a earlier version and it worked

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your php version to minimum `php 7.1.3`

you can see the error in first lines:

```
 - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.0.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.4.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Fix that and after try again please

Comment: but how to upgrade php ?

Comment: It depends on your system, on your localhost, It depends

Comment: will i not lose anything if i upgrade it ?

Comment: It depends what is your configuration, system.. etc... but I advise you to make a backup of your data, but how to upgrade to php7 is another question :)